# Sass: apply a property to a grand-parent with same class

Tags: css, sass

I have the markup:

```
<body class="arabic specific-page">
<div class="child">
<div class="grand-child">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

In my sass I am already inside .specific-page and .child. I would like to apply a specific property if body is .arabic:

what I already have:

```
.specific-page {
  .child{
   .arabic & {
     .grand-child{
```

gets compilet to:

```
.arabic .specific-page .child .grand-child
```

I would like to compile to:

```
.arabic.specific-page .child .grand-child (body has the same class)
```

without changing the selector at the top of the tree, only at child level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using @at-root like so:

```
.specific-page {
  .child{
      @at-root .arabic#{&} {
     .grand-child{
       border: 1px solid red;
     }
   }
}
}
```

This compiles to: `.arabic.specific-page .child .grand-child`, see [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/goexwX).

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you're going to need to alter your SASS a bit. Try

```
.specific-page {
  &.arabic {
    .child {
       .grand-child {
```

Comment: so there is no sass operator where i can do it lower down the tree?

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga not that I am aware of. The `&` isn't to be used to traverse up the selector tree. You can use `@at-root .specific-page.arabic .child .grand-child`. This breaks you out using the compiled selector you're currently nested in and allows you to write a new selector while maintaining the nested look/feel - say for a component.

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga check out my answer using `@at-root` without the need to pass in the full class context again (i.e. no need to specifically write the .specific-page . child .grand-child, just the .arabic modifier) :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `@at-root` and break out of your nesting structure.

```
.specific-page {
  .child{
   .arabic {
     @at-root .arabic.specific-page .child .grand-child{}
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use an @mixin function like this, when i need change some element in middle
of a sass big tree.

The first parameters is the parent element, the target, and the second the class that should have.

`SASS`

```
@mixin parentClass($parentTarget, $aditionalCLass) {

    @at-root #{selector-replace(&, $parentTarget, $parentTarget + $aditionalCLass)} {
        @content;
    }
}
```

###### Sample,

like I need to improve font size in a strong tag, when .txt-target had .txt-strong too

`HTML`

```
   <section class="sample">
        <h1 class="txt-target txt-bold">Sample<strong>Bold</strong>Text</h1>
    </section>
```

`SASS`

```
section{
    .txt-target{
        strong{
            @include parentClass('.txt-target','.txt-bold'){
                font-weight:bold;
                font-size:30px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

```
.arabic.specific-page {
  .child{
     .grand-child{
```

Or (you can switch the order of arabic and specific-page):

```
.arabic{
&.specific-page {
  .child{
     .grand-child{
```